# ELI5 Python groupby code which "collapses" consecutive numbers

Tags: python

I have assembled some code that does what I want from pulling from various SO posts, but I'm not quite sure how it works. Was wondering if someone can save me some time and ELI5 how it works.

Given a list of numbers that may or may not be consecutive:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

list_of_num = [1,3,4,5,6,10,11,13,15,17,18]
for _, value in groupby(enumerate(list_of_num), lambda i_x: i_x[0] - i_x[1]):
    collapsed_nums = map(itemgetter(1), value)
```

The output for each iteration is: [1], [3,4,5,6], [10,11], [13], [15], [17,18] (if converted from map to list)

How does the combination of the lambda function and enumerate work together to produce this output?

Comment: `groupby` isn't standard Python; maybe you need to `import` it from somewhere?

Comment: Updated the post - it's from the itertools module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see how this works by looking at the input and output of the `groubpy` key:

```
list_of_num = [1,3,4,5,6,10,11,13,15,17,18]

>>> for i_x in enumerate(list_of_num):
 ...:     print((i_x, i_x[0] - i_x[1]))
 ...:     
((0, 1), -1)
((1, 3), -2)
((2, 4), -2)
((3, 5), -2)
((4, 6), -2)
((5, 10), -5)
((6, 11), -5)
((7, 13), -6)
((8, 15), -7)
((9, 17), -8)
((10, 18), -8)
```

Breaking it down:

- `enumerate(list_of_num)` - This is an iterable that will emit a tuple of the position of the item in the list, then the value itself
- `groupby(..., lambda i_x: i_x[0] - i_x[1])` - `groupby` takes an iterable and groups together sequential elements where the key (the second argument) returns the same value.
- `lambda i_x: i_x[0] - i_x[1]` - This is a function that takes a 2 or more element sequence and returns the difference between the first two elements. Given that you are passing it the output of `enumerate`, it's always the difference between the number in the list and its position in the list.

Putting it all together - consecutive numbers will have a constant value for the difference between the number and its position in the list, so enumerating over a list of numbers and then grouping by that difference will group together runs of sequential numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your list, its enumeration, and their differences (which is what your key function measures)

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5   6   7   8   9   10   # indices
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 18]  # list
 1  2  2  2  2  5   5   6   7   8   8    # difference (key function value)
```

This is all that key function is doing.  Because the enumeration always increases by one, if the value also increased by one then the difference between the value and the index will remain the same, which means `groupby` will group those items together.